# Shopify import reviews via API?

Tags: api, import, export, shopify, review

I need to import product reviews to my existing Shopify store. I found a way to import product data via CSV, yeah, this is a standard function.

However I need to import reviews using API (e.g. automated way). I tried to look for this ability but I still can't. I can't imagine there is no ability to import product reviews via Shopify API!

Should be I mistaken. Can anybody fix me?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but Shopify doesn't a have review functionality by default. Are you referring to a review app by any chance?

Comment: @drip Should be I meant this app which is built by Shopify https://help.shopify.com/manual/apps/apps-by-shopify/product-reviews/import-export-reviews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Shopify-built Product Reviews app does not have an API. Many merchants use third-party apps to set up their product reviews. [Yotpo](https://apps.shopify.com/yotpo-social-reviews) is a popular option and [they do have an API.](http://apidocs.yotpo.com/)

Comment: does yotpo provide app install status api ?